# Port mapping HTTP server on Debian?

Tags: python, linux, http, ip, raspberry-pi

So I'm a Mac user. I have pretty much no experience with Linux. So when I wanted to host a temporary web server on my Raspberry Pi (running Debian-derived Raspbian), I was stuck.

I'm using `sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the terminal to host a local server on localhost, but I need to map it to mu public IP on port 80. On my MacBook I use [Port Map](http://codingmonkeys.de/portmap/), and that works fine. Is there some software or a command I can do to map this on my 'Pi?

Thanks a bunch!

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on Ubuntu and it will be the same on Debian.

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

This will work even without `sudo` as it serves on non-privileged port 8000

If you want to serve on port 80, you have to use `sudo` and you shall pass port number on command line:

```
$ sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```

There is no need to forward this port, it is served already.

Warning: SimpleHTTPServer is not the most secure web server, be careful with exposing your computer to the public this way.

### Port forwarding using `rinetd`

If you want to do real port forwarding, there is a service called `rinetd`. It is very easy to configure.

Comment: "There is no need to forward this port" why not? "it is served already" only on the local network, in a typical configuration

Comment: @guest - you are right. Added reference to `rinetd`